# Linq Query to get latest of eact defect ID

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

In  **al_jira_defect_out** table i have **Batch_Insert_Timestamp**, **AL_Defect_ID** columns along with other columns.And In this table there will be duplicate AL_Defect_IDs with different Batch_Insert_Timestamp.

As per below code in linq i am  getting all records which are Jira_Status == 0

```
var defects = (from d in db.al_jira_defect_out
    join p in db.al_jira_ref_defect_project on d.Defect_Product_ID.ToString() equals p.al_product_id
    join t in db.al_jira_ref_defect_type on d.Defect_Type_ID equals t.type
    where d.Jira_Status == 0
    select new Issue
    {
        fields = new CreateIssue
        {
            project = new Project
            {
                key = g.jira_project_key
            },
            issuetype = new Issuetype()
            {
                name = t.jira_equivalent
            },
            description = d.Defect_ShortDesc,
            summary = d.Defect_DetailDesc,
            versions = new List<Versions>
            {
                new Versions {name = d.Defect_Release_DetectedIn}
            },
            priority = new Priority
            {
                name = d.Defect_Severity_Name
            },
            customfield_10182 = d.AL_Defect_ID.ToString(),
        }
    }).Select().ToList();
```

i am getting record with AL_Defect_IDs duplicate.
But i required latest records[Max(d.Batch_Insert_Timestamp)] of each d.AL_Defect_ID with all required columns
can any one please help me to get linq query

Comment: You can use groupby and then take max, last, sum etc. in select statement...

Comment: You're using an OR-mapper: don't let db names trickle down into the C# class model. Naming conventions are there for a reason. Also, don't join, use navigation properties. Doing that, it could be as simple as `select Project.Defects.OrderByDescending(d => d.TimeStamp).FirstOrDefault()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you group on `AL_Defect_ID`s, you can order by `Batch_Insert_Timestamp` and take the last (latest) one:

```
var defects = (from d in db.al_jira_defect_out
               join p in db.al_jira_ref_defect_project on d.Defect_Product_ID.ToString() equals p.al_product_id
               join t in db.al_jira_ref_defect_type on d.Defect_Type_ID equals t.type
               where d.Jira_Status == 0
               group new { d, p, t } on d.AL_Defect_ID into dptg
               let dpt = (from dpt in dptg order by dpt.d.Batch_Insert_Timestamp select dpt).Last()
               select new // ... whatever using dpt
```

Your sample code doesn't use `p` in the `select`, so you could leave it out of the `group`ing.

Comment: Tq @NetMage. For the time being i had created stored procedure. I will try this when i was free and let you know if i have any queries